# Using shorthand argument with closure in swift?

Tags: swift, closures

I have created a function which accepts two closures.  Each closure accepts two arguments.  Now i am trying to access the argument with $0,$1.Now when i access $0 it return both the arguments not one where $1 return only second argument.

```
func myFunc(first:Int,second:Int,success:(String,Int)->(),failure:(String,Int)->()){

        if first > second {

            success("Greater Number", first)

        } else {

            failure("Smaller Number", second)
        }
    }
```

Calling function

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    myFunc(first: 2, second: 2, success: {

        print("message is \($0)")
    }, failure: {

        print("error message is \($0)")
    })
}
```

It prints as 
**error message is ("Smaller Number", 2)**

Why not only string is printed?

Comment: When the closure only uses $0 it gets the entire set of inputs as a tuple.  If it accesses $1 also, then $0 refers to the first parameter.  You can work around this situation by using $0.0 to refer to the first parameter.

Comment: And of course, you asked if it was higher or lower. You need a parameter to tests when and is equal.
something like  
  `  if (first >= second) {
// do your staff
}
`
and Why not only string ? 

just print your staff this way 

print("message is \(success)")

other case print("error message is \(failure)")